# Android : ClassCastException getting text from a button

Tags: android, button, classcastexception

I am trying to get text from the `Button` and convert it to a `String` as follows:

```
Button button11 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button11);
String btnText = (String) button11.getText();
```

However, I am getting an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableString cannot be cast to
java.lang.String
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: `getText` read the doc for this method.

Comment: @njzk2 - Anything in particular of interest?

Comment: yes, for example the return type? which is `CharSequence`? (i.e. not `String`)

Comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html section `Casting Objects`

Answer (score 0):

`getText()` returns a `SpannableString`, which is a `CharSequence` that has optional markup rules for things like **bold**, *italics*, etc.

Call `getText().toString()` to get the plain string.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText%28%29

It returns CharSequence according to the documentation. I have no issue calling getText().toString(), but just wanted to clarify for my understanding.